# How do I sign a user in automatically after they create an account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had to override the registrations controller for the create method, so now when a user registers it no longer signs them in automatically after the account is created, but I would like to maintain this behavior.

Currently my create method looks like:

```
   def create
     @user = User.new
     @user.attributes = params[:user]

     if cookies[:invcode]
        @user.inv_code = cookies[:invcode]
        cookies.delete :invcode
     end

     if @user.save
        redirect_to :root
     end
  end
```

Comment: What is your code for signing in? You just have to place it in the `if @user.save` code block ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used a method like `sign_in @user` or like Devise's `sign_in_and_redirect`, you can just use that in the @user.save block in your create method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Devise? If so,

```
if @user.save
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
end
```

or, even better, just copy some of the code from Devises' [registration controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb).

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```